# Full Calendar in CakepPHP

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar

I am following this tutorial: http://duckranger.com/2010/03/fullcalendar-and-cakephp-part-1-set-up/
and I cannot display my fullcalendar.
I uploaded jquery lib into app/webroot/js, css into app/webroot/css,

My Event model:

```
< ?php
 class Event extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Event';
}
?>
```

I got events_controller:

```
 < ?php

class EventsController extends BaseControllerÂ  
{
    var $name = 'Events';
>
    var $helpers = array('Admin','Time','Javascript');
}
```

In views/events i got calendar.ctp:

```
 <?php


    echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
    echo $javascript->link('ui.core.js');
    echo $javascript->link('ui.resizable.js');
    echo $javascript->link('fullcalendar.min.js');
    echo $javascript->link('ui.draggable.js');
    echo $html->css('fullcalendar');
    //Note: to use $html->css as above, the fullcalendar.css 
    //file must be in your app/webroot/css folder.
?>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

And i dont know what to do. Where tu put these lines?:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
    });
```

BTW, i got error name:

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseControllerÂ'
>   not found in D:\PHP
>   Projekty\salon\app\controllers\events_controller.php
>   on line 2

Comment: Doesn't CakePHP use `AppController` as it's base controller? Or have you created and included your own custom controller?

Comment: I changed to AppController, and it shows blank page. It means, cake configuration is working, but fullcalendar is not :(

Comment: And what version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: That's [deprecated code](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1450/Javascript) then; the [Jshelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js) should be used instead. That may or may not be relevant. Do you get any HTML output? A blank page suggests an error.

Comment: I got only default layout. In place where fullcalendar should appera, its blank. Where to put <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
    }); code?

Comment: That code needs to be placed in the `<head>` of your layout. You can use the Js helper, or you can add it manually. The Js helper lets you use the code only on pages where you want the code to appear - putting it in the layout will cause the code to be on every page that uses that layout.

Comment: To clarify - the Js helper is used in the `view`, and will modify the layout when it is rendered. You can also just place the code directly in the layout; but it will always be available.

Answer (score 2):

First On your debugging mode 
app -> Config -> Core.php

Configure::write('debug',2);

It should be 2.

In cakephp all the controller default extend with AppController. If you want to use some extra function than create a component instead a controller.
Load component in Your controller Like 
public $components = array('Session','Email','Cookie', 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie');

You can also use cakephp pulgin for this 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/silasmontgomery/2011/03/02/cakephp_full_calendar_plugin_2